# Dismiss Keyboard when Touching Sibling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

Despite all the "Dismissing Keyboard" questions, there doesn't appear to be one referring to this specific scenario.

I am working on a ViewController with the following (simplified) hierarchy:

- UIView

  - UIScrollView

    - UIStackView

      - PLCustomViewOne

        - UIButton
        - UITextField
      - PLCustomViewTwo

        - UIButton
        - UITextField

The ViewController is loaded from an XIB as are the two PLCustomView's. I can't seem to get the view to `endEditing` (dismiss the keyboard) when the user selects anything contained by the UIStackViews.

Adding a gesture recognizer to the view certainly will work; however, this requires that every view in the hierarchy gets the gesture recognizer added to it, which doesn't seem very scalable. There are actually quite a few subviews on the real version of this.

I have tried adding the dismissal in `touchesBegan` to the UIView subclass of each of the custom views, but this only dismisses the keyboard if the user touches the view which is containing the firstResponder. For example, if the textField in `PLCustomViewOne` is active then touching anywhere else in that view dismisses the keyboard, but touching outside it, say, `PLCustomViewTwo`, does not.

Comment: Did you try [self.scrollvoew endEditing];

Comment: Are you suggesting adding `scrollView.endEditing(true)` in the top-level UIView? The issue is that on that top-level UIView, `touchesBegan` isn't being called.

Comment: @MichaelVoccola Please give feedvack or additional info if the answer below did not solve your problem. If it did, please close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired result by adding the following to the custom views:

```
private func addTapToResignFirstResponder () {
    let action = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dismissFirstResponder"))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(action)
}

func dismissFirstResponder () {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
}
```

where `addTapToResignFirstResponder()` is called in the `UIView`'s initialization.

This globally dismisses the first responder regardless of where it is without needing a reference.

`dismissFirstResponder()` can also be overridden in subclasses for additional flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller class, create outlets to your two custom views (via ctrl-drag from storyboard)

```
@IBOutlet weak var customViewOne: PLCustomViewOne!
@IBOutlet weak var customViewTwo: PLCustomViewTwo!
```

From these, you should be able to access your UITextField instances, say by

```
customViewOne.textField
customViewTwo.textField
```

(Preferably if you make this property non-private in your custom class). Also (in you view controller class) create a private `UITextField` property to hold the (possibly) current (/most recently used) text field.

```
private var currentTextField: UITextField?
```

Overload the `viewDidLoad` method of your `UIViewController` subclass to initialize the delegates for the two "public" text field instances

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the user input in the text fields through delegate callbacks (and set tags)
    customViewOne.textField.delegate = self
    customViewOne.textField.delegate = self
}
```

Moreover, use the two `textFieldShouldReturn(...)` and `textFieldDidBeginEditing(...)` methods of the `UITextFieldDelegate` to resign the (active) text fields status's as first responder and to update the `currentTextField` reference, respectively.

```
// UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // User finished typing (hit return): hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    currentTextField = textField
}
```

Finally (also in view controller class), resign any possibly current text field as first responder, in case **any** of your two buttons is pressed in-middle-of editing/or when touchesBegan in **any** of the UIView

```
... user does action/tap/gesture elsewhere {
    if let currentTextField = currentTextField {
        currentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

The key here is that you keep track of which text field is first responder (by `currentTextField` property in view controller), and resign just this text field.

Comment: This does solve the issue. It also adds some additional flexibility in accessing the current textField in a subview at the expense of additional complexity.

Comment: @MichaelVoccola happy to help.